# How can I insert values?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO service%s (name) VALUES (%s)" %service_id %self.name)
```

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I have a services1, services2, ... sql tables and I want to insert name values to this table. I try this code but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, try this:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO service%s (name) VALUES (%s)" %(service_id, self.name))
```

A better & cleaner approach is to

1st save your query under a variable e.g:

`query = '''INSERT INTO service{0} (name) VALUES ({1})'''.format(service_id,self.name)`

Then:

c.execute(query)

But also to avoid sql injection you might go for the '?' in your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO service%s (name) VALUES (%s)" %service_id %self.name)
```

is not correct syntax.

The right syntax is:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO service%s (name) VALUES (%s)" %(service_id, self.name))
```